# how to add drive sql server dll in laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I need your help, I'm having problems when migrating table to sql server database, I've added the driver in the `php/ext` folder but when the migration always fails, I don't forget to change the `php.ini` file and add extension: `php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll` but it still fails to migrate please help

Command output:

```
      PDO::__construct()
PS D:\kerja\INDOPRIMA\ERP\erpindowire> php artisan migrate
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_sqlsrv' (tried: C:/Bitnami/wappstack-7.4.8-0/php/ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv (The specified module could not be found.), C:/Bitnami/wappstack-7.4.8-0/php/ext\php_php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_sqlsrv.dll' (tried: C:/Bitnami/wappstack-7.4.8-0/php/ext\php_sqlsrv.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:/Bitnami/wappstack-7.4.8-0/php/ext\php_php_sqlsrv.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Sure you edited the correct php.ini file? `php artisan migrate` most likely uses the CLI variant, not the server one

Comment: yes i edited php.ini in folder php

Comment: The problem isn't  with Laravel. Could you show how did you add these extensions in your php.ini?

Comment: in php.ini i using like this
extension=php_sqlsrv
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that php is not locating your extensions in the `ext` folder, it will show that message with every other php command, not just Laravel ones.

Based on your last comment you're using the wrong syntax to load the extension.

First, ensure you have both the `php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll` and `php_sqlsrv.dll` on your extension folder.

Finally, change the way you declared the extension to this:

```
extension=sqlsrv
extension=pdo_sqlsrv
```

Note: `php_sqlsrv.dll` would work too, but not `php_sqlsrv` or `sqlsrv.dll`.

From the comments of the php.ini file:

```
; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename
;
; For example:
;
;   extension=mysqli
; 
; When the extension library to load is not located in the default extension
; directory, You may specify an absolute path to the library file:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/mysqli.so
;
; Note : The syntax used in previous PHP versions ('extension=<ext>.so' and
; 'extension='php_<ext>.dll') is supported for legacy reasons and may be
; deprecated in a future PHP major version. So, when it is possible, please
; move to the new ('extension=<ext>) syntax.
;
```

Comment: hello i still got error

PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv' (tried: C:/Bitnami/wappstack-7.4.8-0/php/ext\sqlsrv (The specified module could not be found.), C:/Bitnami/wappstack-7.4.8-0/php/ext\php_sqlsrv.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv' (tried: C:/Bitnami/wappstack-7.4.8-0/php/ext\pdo_sqlsrv (The specified module could not be found.), C:/Bitnami/wappstack-7.4.8-0/php/ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: i got erorrr and when a i look in phpmyinfo still now show  pdo_sqlsrv after i following your answer

Comment: Now the problem is that you downloaded the wrong files, you have to download according yo your php version, architecture (PHP x64 or PHP x86) and the thread safety (ts or nts). You can check all this info in your phpinfo.